# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when an Angular Component is tested with synchronous Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-test

I have a simple component which uses a service returning an Observable. Such Observable is used to control the creation of an html element via `*ngIf`.

Here the code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 *ngIf="stuff$ | async as obj">Hello {{obj.name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
  ) {}

  stuff$;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.stuff$ = this.myService.getStuff();
  }
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  getStuff() {
    const stuff = {name: 'I am an object'};
    return of(stuff).pipe(delay(100));
  }
}
```

As you can see, `getStuff()` returns and Observable with a `delay` and everything works as expected.

Now I remove the `delay` and I get the following error on the console

*Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: null'. Current value: 'ngIf: [object Object]'.*

[This is a Stackbliz that reproduces the case.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isgjfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy.service.ts)

Is this inevitable? Is there a way to avoid this error?
This small example replicates a real world example, where `MyService` queries a back end, so the delay.

This is for me relevant because I would like to be able to run tests in a synchronous way simulating the real backend and, when I try such an approach, I get the same result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error basically says that one change triggered another change. It happens only without `delay(100)` because RxJS is strictly sequential and subscriptions happen synchronously. If you use `delay(100)` (even if you use just `delay(0)` it makes the emission asynchronous so it happens in another frame and is caught by another change detection cycle.

A very simple way to avoid this is just wrapping assigning to a variable with `setTimeout()` or with `NgZone.run()`.

Or more "Rx way" is using `subscribeOn(async)` operator:

```
import { asyncScheduler } from 'rxjs';
import { observeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

return of(stuff).pipe(
  observeOn(asyncScheduler)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change the model synchronously in the `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook, you can trigger change detection to avoid the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.stuff$ = this.myService.getStuff();
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wx4h3o?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your observable **after** initializing the view. Try:

```
@Input() name: string;
stuff$ = this.myService.getStuff();
```

Or:

```
ngOnInit() { // or even in constructor()
    this.stuff$ = this.myService.getStuff();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you handle stuff$ as @Input when you try to get it from the myService, too? It's a kind of conflict while rendering.

Maybe ngAfterViewChecked would work better instead of ngAfterViewInit. But the solution still isn't very nice.

Comment: I thought the same but look carefully. It is `@Input() name: string;` and the next line is `stuff$`

Comment: I removed `@Input() name` since it is not relevant